# How to fix Kafka 3.x error parameter -zookeeper?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

My version https://dlcdn.apache.org/kafka/3.1.0/kafka_2.13-3.1.0.tgz . Run on Ubuntu 21.10, OpenJDK 11. I follow guide at https://github.com/donhuvy/kafka-for-developers-using-spring-boot/blob/master/SetUpKafka.md#how-to-create-a-topic- . My command

[image]

```
donhuvy@ubuntu:~/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.1.0/bin$ ./kafka-topics.sh --create --topic test-topic -zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 4
Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: z is not a recognized option
    at joptsimple.OptionException.unrecognizedOption(OptionException.java:108)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.validateOptionCharacters(OptionParser.java:633)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleShortOptionCluster(OptionParser.java:528)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleShortOptionToken(OptionParser.java:523)
    at joptsimple.OptionParserState$2.handleArgument(OptionParserState.java:59)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.parse(OptionParser.java:396)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicCommandOptions.<init>(TopicCommand.scala:567)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:47)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
donhuvy@ubuntu:~/Downloads/kafka_2.13-3.1.0/bin$
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I suggest following the official Apache Kafka website as it has latest commands (also zookeeper flag would have needed two dashes, anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New version of Kafka, use

```
./kafka-topics.sh --create --topic test-topic --bootstrap-server  localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 4
```

[image]